# Simplifying Matrix Expressions Using the Inverse

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have $ABC = D$, where A, B, C, D are all square matrices.

Could I simplify this expression by doing $ABB^{-1}C  = DB^{-1}$

Which solves to $AC = DB^{-1}$

Essentially when simplifying matrix expressions, can I insert a multiplication of the inverse matrix anywhere in the equation? Or can it only be at the beginning or end.

Thanks.

Comment: Your specific transformation is not valid. You *can* insert the identity anywhere, in the shape of $XX^{-1}.$ Also even if your transformation *were* valid, it "solves" to $AC=DB^{-1}$ and not to just $D^{-1}.$

Comment: Sorry, I mean to write "Solves to $AC = DB^{-1}$, does that make it valid?

Comment: No that is not valid. You multiplied by $B^{-1}$ in between $A$ and $C$ on the left side, but on the right you multiplied by $B^{-1}$ on the right.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. Sweet as thank you!

Comment: Note that if $ABC=D$ it *is* possible to solve for any of $A,B,C$ in terms of the others. Example $A=DC^{-1}B^{-1}.$